# How do set a width and height of an Image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

New to `Swift` and `iOS` programming in general. I couldn't figure out how to set a width and height of an image.
For example,

```
  let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "background.png")
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not set the `UIImageView`'s frame size instead? Unless you truly want to draw a brand new `UIImage` using a context.

Answer (score 30):

My suggestion is.

Instead of set size of **image** you should set size of `UIImageView` and then put this **image** on it so, size of **image** will be display as per your requirement.

Such like,

```
var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 150, 150, 150)); // set as you want
var image = UIImage(named: "myImage.png");
imageView.image = image;
self.view.addSubview(imageView);
```

Comment: What if your imageView is already declared and has width and height constraints? How do you change it then?

Comment: imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 150, width: 150, height: 150)

Comment: this didn't work for me because it conflicts with the Auto Layout constraints the imageView has for width and height.

Comment: To make the suggestion work in Swift 3 or later, replace the first line with:   var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))

Answer (score 19):

You have this code, this code set width and height and save the same position.

```
/**
Resize UIImageView
:param: UImage
:param: new size CGSize
:return: new UImage rezised
*/
    func imageResize (#image:UIImage, sizeChange:CGSize)-> UIImage{

        let hasAlpha = true
        let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Use scale factor of main screen

        // Create a Drawing Environment (which will render to a bitmap image, later)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sizeChange, !hasAlpha, scale)

        image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: sizeChange))

        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        // Clean up the Drawing Environment (created above)
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return scaledImage
    }

     let size = CGSizeMake(100, 150)

    myImageView.image! = imageResize(myImageView.image!,sizeChange: size)
```

Work in viewDidLoad or refresh "reloadInputViews()" your UIImageView ;-)

**

### EDIT

**

Hi create this extends if you want.

**Create File Extends.Swift** and **add** this code (add **import foundation** where you want change height)

```
/**
    Extension UIView
*/
extension UIView {
    /**
    Set x Position

    :param: x CGFloat
    */
    func setX(#x:CGFloat) {
        var frame:CGRect = self.frame
        frame.origin.x = x
        self.frame = frame
    }
    /**
    Set y Position

    :param: y CGFloat
    */
    func setY(#y:CGFloat) {
        var frame:CGRect = self.frame
        frame.origin.y = y
        self.frame = frame
    }
    /**
    Set Width

    :param: width CGFloat
    */
    func setWidth(#width:CGFloat) {
        var frame:CGRect = self.frame
        frame.size.width = width
        self.frame = frame
    }
    /**
    Set Height

    :param: height CGFloat
    */
    func setHeight(#height:CGFloat) {
        var frame:CGRect = self.frame
        frame.size.height = height
        self.frame = frame
    }
}
```

**For Use (inherits Of UIView)**

```
inheritsOfUIView.setHeight(height: 100)
button.setHeight(height: 100)
view.setHeight(height: 100)
```

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 3.0** version *(from @YannickSteph)*

```
extension UIImage {

    func imageResize (sizeChange:CGSize)-> UIImage{

        let hasAlpha = true
        let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Use scale factor of main screen

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sizeChange, !hasAlpha, scale)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: sizeChange))

        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        return scaledImage!
    }

}
```

Comment: Put the height and width in a `CGSize` object and pass it to the `imageResize` method while calling it.

Answer (score 10):

if you want to keep the aspect ratio, here is an extension method for 
Swift 3 :

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

    func resize(maxWidthHeight : Double)-> UIImage? {

        let actualHeight = Double(size.height)
        let actualWidth = Double(size.width)
        var maxWidth = 0.0
        var maxHeight = 0.0

        if actualWidth > actualHeight {
            maxWidth = maxWidthHeight
            let per = (100.0 * maxWidthHeight / actualWidth)
            maxHeight = (actualHeight * per) / 100.0
        }else{
            maxHeight = maxWidthHeight
            let per = (100.0 * maxWidthHeight / actualHeight)
            maxWidth = (actualWidth * per) / 100.0
        }

        let hasAlpha = true
        let scale: CGFloat = 0.0

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: maxHeight), !hasAlpha, scale)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: maxHeight)))

        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        return scaledImage
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This question is from several years ago but comes up as I was trying to resize an image. There are apparently new ways that are much easier in SWIFTUI (not UIKit). This works for me:

```
Image("yourImage").resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
```

Comment: You have to mention that this's a SwiftUI Code, not UIKit