# Title Image UINavigationBar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to add a title image to my nav bar in the entirety of my app. The below line of code in my App Delegate works, but the image is tiled to fit... Is there a way I can set the dimensions and position?

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "tmp logo.png"), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of image, by setting the size of UIImageView.

```
  var imageNew = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100));// define 
  the size of the view here. 
  var image = UIImage(named: "myImage.png");
  imageNew.image = image;
  self.view.addSubview(imageNew);
```

Pl. refer to the below stackoverflow response, which provides the solution 
[How do set a width and height of an Image in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709244/how-do-set-a-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-swift)