# iOS. Tab bar icon is low quality on simulator. How to fix?

Tags: ios

I've created 3 icons:

```
ic_tags.png - 22x22
ic_tags@2x.png - 44x44
ic_tags@4x.png - 88x88
```

[image]

But I still see that the icon is low quality.
And when I try to make image bigger it becomes bigger on the screen

[image]

Comment: have you checked how it looks on an actual device?

Comment: @nhgrif When I try 44x44 as default size it looks very large. What the problem can be?

Comment: It *can* matter.  The display on actual Apple iOS devices is usually much higher quality than most people's monitors.  But even if you're on a retina MacBook pro, there are some discrepancies between how it is displayed on an iOS device and in the simulator... but in this case, the problem is simply you're using the wrong size images.

Comment: Isn't 44x44 a bit big default size for tab bar icons? [Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) say _about_ 25x25 for @1x.

Answer (score -1):

22px is actually just a really small image. You should probably make the image itself bigger and then make the ImageView smaller to achieve a higher resolution.

Comment: Thank you. When I make image bigger it becomes bigger in the screen. And this is standard tab bar controller. How can I change imageview size in it?

Comment: if your imageview is made through storyboard. You can make it bigger in the right sideview. There's a button that looks like a measuring ruler. Under that menu, there's a "width" and "height" that you can set.

Otherwise, you can initialize your image with a `CGRectMake`, like so: `var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 150, 150, 150));`. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709244/how-do-set-a-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-swift)

Comment: No I use standard Tab bar controller, which is already built

Comment: There's no such thing as an `ImageView` in this scenario @FlaqueDeau. We're talking about the default `UITabBar`.