# UISlider Custom Thumb Shape

Tags: swift, uislider

I want to modify a bit the `UISlider`. To be exact, I want the thumb to have a **custom shape** (square/rectangle with rounded corners and bottom shadow).

The only answers that I found were something like "Create your own custom slider". But I don't know how to do that and it would take me a lot more than just trying to modify a bit the `UISlider`.

From my research I found that you can assign an image to the thumb.

So my question is the following: **Is there any way of "creating" a `UIImage` with a `CGRect` so I can have any shape that I want (a square/rectangle in this case)? And of course, is and implementation with the `UISlider` even possible?**

Comment: just change the image size

Comment: This seems like a couple of different questions to me... A bit confusing. I suggest asking a more specific question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, create an image from of your shape.

Second, [Edit the image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709244/how-do-set-a-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-swift).

Third, Set the image of the slider for specific states:

```
for state: UIControlState in [.Normal, .Selected, .Application, .Reserved] {

    slider.setThumbImage(yourImageThatHasBeenResized), forState: state)

}
```

I don't believe you can put a `UILabel` on a `UISlider`. You would have to create the label, then align it to the same x as the slider.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out. I have found an answer on SO that apparently works. And yes, it's aligning the label with the thumb every time it changes value.

Comment: If you want another image for the thumb while sliding the slider, use .highlighted state.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to resize your image. You can have images provided for both retina an non-retina devices. "@2x" before the image extension is a simple signifier for your program to take care of the resizing.

You can set the images like so: (**Swift 4**)

```
for state: UIControlState in [.normal, .selected, .application, .reserved] {

    slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "sliderThumbNormal@2x.png"), for: state)

}

// if you want a different image while dragging the slider, use the hightlighted state      
slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "sliderThumbSelected@2x.png"), for: .highlighted)
```