# How to set a size for UIImage in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a simple UIImage that I want as a map annotation. The original image is 300x500 but I want it down to 20*26.

```
var img = UIImage(named: "annotation")
img.size.width = 20
```

This gives me a "Cannot assign to property: 'size' is a get-only property" error.

How can I resize a UIImage without embedding it in any views? (Map annotations are strictly UIImages)

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709244/how-do-set-a-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-swift I think you will find your answer there :)

Comment: Google is your friend as a developer — https://nshipster.com/image-resizing/